# Converting .fdshape to .shp or other QGIS readable format

Tags: shapefile, convert

I have been searching for a solution to being able to read .fdshape extension files in QGIS with no luck. It seems that the data had to be converted from .shp to .fdshape in the first place so I was wondering if there is an easy way of getting this information converted back?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, QGIS doesn't support the .fdshape file extension.
But maybe you can go along with the converter you can find [here](https://stellarsupport.deere.com/en_US/support/jdrx_converter/)? It allows you to export/convert .fdshape files to .shp files. 
There's also a [manual](https://stellarsupport.deere.com/en_US/support/jdrx_converter/jdrx_userguide.pdf) for that tool.